# Shrinking the progressdialog

Tags: android

I have a progressdialog in an asynctask that I show on a splash layout.  How do I change the overall size of the progressdialog--I want to scale it to be smaller overall.  Also, how do I move the progressdialog so that it appears vertically more at the bottom of my layout rather than in the middle.  I've seen this done in another application, but I'm not sure how they did it.  Thanks in advance for any help.

```
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPreExecute();

    dialog = ProgressDialog.show(Splash.this,
        getResources().getString(R.string.splashCheckInterenetConnection),
        getResources().getString(R.string.splashPleaseWait), true);
}
```

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/splashImage"
        android:src="@drawable/splash"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    />
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like in [#7819235](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7819235/how-to-reduce-the-size-of-progressdialog-in-android):

Play with android progressBar style

```
<ProgressBar android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall" <-- play with this
 android:layout_gravity="center" />
```

or

```
mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(android.R.attr.progressBarStyleSmall);
```