# How to reduce the size of Progressdialog in android?

Tags: android

I want the display the progress dialog like activity indicator as like in iPhone, So I want to 
reduce the size of it.

Could any one give me a idea on this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Play with android progressBar style

```
<ProgressBar android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall" <-- play with this
  android:layout_gravity="center"
/>
```

## EDIT:

See [this](http://sree.cc/google/android/code-for-creating-a-progress-bar-in-android) post, and example of progressbar created using code

Comment: I am creating progress dialog in coding, how to same above thing in java coding..

Answer (score 2):

Try this way:

```
mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(android.R.attr.progressBarStyleSmall);
```