# How to reduce the height and width of progress dialog?

Tags: android

I want to reduce the height and width of progress dialog and display it smaller in the middle of the screen.

Answer (score 2):

u can use the assync task for the purpose...make a graphics of an image and apply the rotation animation..in this mAnimation is the imageview u want to rotate...place this imageview at the centre of the screen and make invisible at post execute..in post execute clear the animation and do other stuff

```
 private class LoadAssync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        mAnimation.startAnimation(anim);
    }

    protected Void doInBackground(final String... args) {
        //do the task here

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(final Void unused) {
        mAnimation.clearAnimation();
                    mAnimation.setVisibility(View.GONE); 

    }


}
```

in rotation.xml

```
  <rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:duration="1200"
android:fromDegrees="0"
android:pivotX="50%"
android:pivotY="50%"
android:repeatCount="infinite"
android:toDegrees="360"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator" >

 </rotate>
```

hope this helps

Comment: Progress Images is replaced but I am getting the progress dialog background window. I dont want that. I want to remove that too.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is to create a custom style with width set to `wrap_content`

```
<style name="DialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <!--Other custom stuff if needed-->
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
</style>
```

Then add this style to the `ProgressDialog`

```
final ProgressDialog mDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity(), R.style.DialogStyle);
mDialog.setMessage("Loading... Please wait...");
mDialog.setCancelable(false);
mDialog.show();
mDialog.setContentView(avLoadingIndicatorView);
```

## Demo

[image]

Comment: what is avLoadingIndicatorView?

Comment: @Prabhakaran the view controller that you want to display the loading bar onto

Answer (score 0):

Just refer the answer given at

[How to reduce the size of Progressdialog in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7819235/how-to-reduce-the-size-of-progressdialog-in-android)

take the hint and solve your problem :)