# How to change progress dialog box size in android?

Tags: android, user-interface

I used this method to create progress dialog box.

But it not fit with the screen size. I want to minimize size of this progress dialog box.

This is the (AsyncTask) code i used:

```
ProgressDialog myPd_bar;

@Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            myPd_bar=new ProgressDialog(AppleModles.this);
              //myPd_bar.setMessage("Loading....");
              myPd_bar.setTitle("Please Wait..");
              myPd_bar.setProgressStyle(myPd_bar.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
              myPd_bar.setProgress(0);
              myPd_bar.setMax(30);
              myPd_bar.show();
              new Thread(new Runnable() {
                   @Override
                    public void run() {
                          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                          try
                          {
                                while(myPd_bar.getProgress()<=myPd_bar.getMax())
                                {
                                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                                    handle.sendMessage(handle.obtainMessage());
                                      if(myPd_bar.getProgress()==myPd_bar.getMax())
                                      {
                                            myPd_bar.dismiss();
                                      }

                                }
                          }catch(Exception e){}
                    }
              }).start();


            super.onPreExecute();
        }

Handler handle=new Handler(){
                  @Override
                  public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        super.handleMessage(msg);
                        myPd_bar.incrementProgressBy(5);
                  }
            };
```

Can anyone help me to minimize this progress dialog box size?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to reduce the size of Progressdialog in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7819235/how-to-reduce-the-size-of-progressdialog-in-android)

Answer (score 5):

Maybe this helps for fitting with the screen size :

```
myPd_bar.show();
Window window = myPd_bar.getWindow();
window.setLayout(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

Comment: for use LayoutParams which one i should import??

Comment: import android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams;

Answer (score 0):

This will solve this problem ,this should written after show

```
progressbar.getWindow().setLayout(width,height);
```